# Android Gradle: archive output directory in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

My Android Gradle project uses a combination of `buildTypes` (DEV,TEST,LIVE - in accordance with our staging process) and `productFlavors` (Different flavours of our app) to create multiple APKs with different signing certificates and Proguard configuration. This works fine so far, as the output of the different flavours is separated in different folders when building with *`$ gradlew assemble`* (without specifying a specific flavour and/or buildType).

Sample build/outputs directory after build:

```
/app/build/outputs/
                   apk/
                       app-flavor1-LIVE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.apk
                       app-flavor2-LIVE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.apk
                       app-flavor3-LIVE-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.apk
                       app-flavor1-DEV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.apk   
                       ...
                    lint-results-flavor1LIVE-fatal_files/...
                    lint-results-flavor2LIVE-fatal_files/...
                    ...
                    proguard/
                             flavor1/
                                     LIVE/...
                                     TEST/...
                             flavor2/
                                     LIVE/...
                             ...
```

The question remains, how can this build output be archived (as an artifact or something) during a Jenkins-Build. Jenkins allows the selection of files for archiving, but the folder hierarchy gets deleted during this process.

Long story short: How do I archive the whole `build/outputs` directory in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a post build action **Archive the artifacts** and in **Files to archive** input field add a pattern (relative to project root):

`build/**/*.apk`

Comment: This archives the APKs only - I need also to preserve the proguard config.

Comment: What is the pattern for proguard config? At this pattern after comma.

Comment: The problem is, that the files of the proguard output of all flavors are named the same (dump.txt, seeds.txt, ...)

Comment: But as far as I know every file is named differently for every flavor?